# Haskell, parameterized datatype converting to String

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Here is my datatype:

```
data Foo a =  Value Integer
           |Boo a
```

and I have a function for converting the Foo datatype to String:

```
showFoo::Show a=> Foo a -> String
showFoo (Value n) = show n
showFoo (Boo a) = show a
```

For example: showFoo (Value 10) becomes: "10", but for showFoo(Boo "S"), it becomes: "\"S\"" but I need only "S".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This boils down to the behaviour of `show` with strings.
`show` is designed to give machine-readable output, it's not a pretty-printer, 
so it puts inverted commas round all strings. That way it can tell the 
difference between `10` and `"10"` when it's reading them back in.

Your `showFoo` function is clearly not designed to be in the `show` family, 
since it obliterates the `Value` and `Boo` tags, so using `show` isn't really what
you mean.

Possible solutions:

1. Give in, go the whole hog and derive `Show`.
2. If `a` is always a String, change your data type and don't use `show`.
3. Learn about type classes some more and define your own `Showish` class.
   Use `-XFlexibleInstances` and `-XOverlappingInstances` to override 
   the instance for String, and don't use quotes.
4. Hack it by using `init.tail.show $ a`

Answer (score 1):

That's just a result of you using GHCi and it showing the previous result. Try this in a compiled program or try running (in GHCi) `putStrLn (showFoo (Boo "S"))` and you will see that calling `show` on a string results in a single set of quotes.

Comment: I understand your point, but I can not change signature of the function (putStrLn can't be used).

Comment: I sympathize with you, but I can't (or am not motivated to) help when there are artificial constraints. I suppose you could do something like `filter (/='"') (show a)`  (or just conditionally drop `"` if they are the first and last characters).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the fundamental problem is that the OP wants `show "foo"` to result in "foo"`. I don't think not wanting to put a function `Foo a -> String` into the IO monad and always write to console is an "artificial constraint" on the solution.